# Conditional jump to register

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I want to get these commands:

```
jl some_label(%rip)
# or
jl *%rax
```

in my asm program that I am writing for Intel x64 architecture.

GCC says that "operand type mismatch for jl" when I try to compile this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conditional jumps are relative on x86. You can use an "inverted" conditional jump followed by an unconditional jump:

```
  jge   skip_jump
  jmp   *%rax       # AT&T syntax
skip_jump:
```

The equivalent NASM syntax is `jmp rax`.  Either way, it sets RIP = RAX, so it's a register-indirect jump.

Comment: I have to insert my binary code to another binary file and when I try to run my code it can't use any labels because they are computed with other addresses. That is why I can't use any labels in my code.

Comment: The target label for a conditional jump will be converted into a relative offset by the assembler. I don't know what you mean by "computed with other addresses". For example, if the size of the `jmp %rax` instruction was 4 bytes, then the `jge skip_jump` would simply become `7D 04` (or `04 7D` when written with the LSB first).

Comment: I understand what you mean, but on practice I can see absolute addresses when programm is linked to the executable file. I would not have any problems with labels if they could have been represented as relative offsets, but I must compute the offset of a label any time I want to use it for a jump.

Comment: The addresses might be shown as absolute by the disassembler, but there's no `Jxx absolute` instruction. Calculating the jump offset for a forward jump used to skip a piece of code is trivial; it's equal to the size of the code you want to skip.

Comment: LSB first? How does that even make sense here?

Comment: @harold: uh, you're right.. not sure what I was thinking there. It would simply be `7D 04`.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that in obj-file jump addresses are stored as relative offsets, but not in an executable file. Now I use the obj-file to load it in other binary and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Conditionally jumping over the indirect `jmp rax` is normally the way to go.

Another option is to use `cmov` to modify the target address:

```
  ## Normally worse than jge, but worth considering
    lea       stay_here(%rip), %rdx         # pick any register
    cmovge    %rdx, %rax
    jmp       *%rax
stay_here:
```

This is larger code-size and more uops, but only one total branch on the taken path.  Also, the default prediction for indirect branch targets is usually `+0` (i.e. the next instruction) if the BTB has no history for it, so it may predict correctly in cases where predictors are cold.

Other than that, jumping to the next instruction is not special-cased and still needs a correct prediction, and still potentially slows down the front-end.

On some CPUs with simple / weak indirect branch prediction, merging the condition into the indirect branch will almost certainly hurt, because it's one extra possible branch target.

**But if you find that the `jge` / `jmp` combination isn't predicting well, this would be worth trying as a way to mix it up.**